# I re-installed ICP and I got the following error CWOAU0061E

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

My last ICP installation had no issues but this one is giving me this error.

`“CWOAU0061E: The OAuth service provider could not find the client because the client name is not valid. Contact your system administrator to resolve the problem.”`

During my installation of ICP-EE 2.1.0.1, I had no errors but it is when I tried to log into the console, I got the error:

I even waited an hour and the error was still happening.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem was related to the following directories:

- `/opt/ibm`
- `/opt/kubernetes`

The two directories listed above were installed from my previous ICP environment but the [official uninstall steps](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_2.1.0/installing/uninstall.html) of ICP didn't remove them.

1. I uninstall ICP again
2. Made sure the two directories were gone
3. Reinstalled ICP again and it worked